# Generating Buttons in Rows and Columns with empty places

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, cgrect

I want to generate a grid with views. I need from 1 row, 1 column up to 3 rows, 6 columns.

my code now is working if i want, that all views are in their place:

```
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
```

but i want to leave some places empty, for example i want to do things like:

```
*  *  *  *  *
*           *
*  *  *  *  *
```

or:

```
*  *    *  *
   *    * 
*          *
```

my code:

.m

```
-(void) generateCardViews {
int positionsLeftInRow = CARDS_PER_ROW;
int j = 0; // j = ROWNUMBER (j = 0) = ROW1, (j = 1) = ROW2...

for (int i = 0; i < [self.gameModel.cards count]; i++) {
NSInteger value = ((CardModel *)self.gameModel.cards[i]).value;

CGFloat x = (i % CARDS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % CARDS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 285;
if (j == 1) {
    x += 80; // set additional indent (horizontal displacement)
}
if (j == 2) {
    x -= 160;
}

CGFloat y = j * 122 + j * 40 + 158;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);




CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];


}
```

how can i do this?

EDIT:
Now with my Code:
if gameModel.cards count = 18 (get this from my model) and if CARS_PER_ROW = 6 i get:

```
*  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *
```

if gameModel.cards count = 12 (get this from my model) and if CARS_PER_ROW = 5 i get:

```
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *
```

Comment: can you show the output you are getting instead the desire one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create all the frame's in an arrary, and then generate buttons from the arrary.